# Validação de datas no model Asp Net Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-validation

Tenho um modelo e queria validar a data final (que deve ser igual ou maior a data inicial)

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ModelId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Início")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fim")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? FinishDate { get; set; }

}
```

Alguma ideia de como validar um campo com base em outro em um modelo?

Comment: você esta usando dataannotations?

Comment: Estou usando sim

Comment: @WallaceReis foi colocado as duas versões a ASPNetCore mudou somente a classe de interface o resto a implementação é igual a anterior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Versão anterior ao [ASPNET CORE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/)

Deve ser criado um classe Customizada que herda da classe abstrata [ValidationAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) para validação do servidor e a [Interface IClientValidatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable(v=vs.118).aspx) para validações cliente, o exemplo básico para validar se uma data é maior ou igual a outra é:

Crie uma classe e herde e implemente respectivamente [ValidationAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) e [IClientValidatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
public class DateTimeCompareAttribute : 
        ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable

{
    public string NameCompare { get; set; }
    public DateTimeCompareAttribute(string nameCompare)
    {
        NameCompare = nameCompare;
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, 
                                                ValidationContext validationContext)
    {            
        if (validationContext.ObjectInstance != null)
        {
            Type _t = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();
            PropertyInfo _d = _t.GetProperty(NameCompare);
            if (_d != null)
            {
                DateTime _dt1 = (DateTime)value;
                DateTime _dt0 = (DateTime)_d
                     .GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
                if (_dt1 != null &&
                    _dt0 != null &&
                    _dt0 <= _dt1)
                {
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }
            }
        }
        return new ValidationResult("Final Date is less than Initial Data");
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(
                                                  ModelMetadata metadata, 
                                                  ControllerContext context)
    {
        ModelClientValidationRule rules = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "datetimecompare"
        };

        rules.ValidationParameters.Add("param", NameCompare);            
        yield return rules;
    }
}
```

Após a elaboração dessa classe tem que configurar na classe que vai ser validata mediante esse atributo da seguinte forma:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ModelId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Início")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fim")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
    //configuração para verificar se a data é maior ou igual a que foi dita no parâmetro
    [DateTimeCompare("StartDate")] 
    public DateTime? FinishDate { get; set; }

}
```

essa configuração já valida os dados no servidor, mas, para ficar uma validação completa é legal adicione um trecho `javascript` ([jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)) para também ter a validação cliente, ***exemplo***:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $.validator.addMethod('datetimecompare', function (value, element, params) {
            return Date.parse(value) >= Date.parse($(params).val());
        }, '');
        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("datetimecompare", ["param"], 
         function (options) {
            options.rules["datetimecompare"] = "#" + options.params.param;
            options.messages["datetimecompare"] = options.message;
        });
    </script>
}
```

com essas configurações vai validar a cliente que é o `javascript` e a do servidor.

---

### Versão para [ASPNET CORE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/)

Para [ASPNET CORE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/) tem uma mudança na classe de `Interface` que a responsável em fazer a validação no lado cliente é a [Interface IClientModelValidator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.validation.iclientmodelvalidator), mas, as mudanças são minimas, observe a classe `DateTimeCompareAttribute`:

```
public class DateTimeCompareAttribute :
        ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    public string NameCompare { get; set; }
    public DateTimeCompareAttribute(string nameCompare)
    {
        NameCompare = nameCompare;
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
                                                ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (validationContext.ObjectInstance != null)
        {
            Type _t = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();
            PropertyInfo _d = _t.GetProperty(NameCompare);
            if (_d != null)
            {
                DateTime _dt1 = (DateTime)value;
                DateTime _dt0 = (DateTime)_d
                     .GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
                if (_dt1 != null &&
                    _dt0 != null &&
                    _dt0 <= _dt1)
                {
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }
            }
        }
        return new ValidationResult("Final Date is less than Initial Data");
    }

    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }            
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-datetimecompare", ErrorMessageString);
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-datetimecompare-param", NameCompare);
    }
}
```

Após a criação dessa classe o resto continue seguindo o exemplo para versão anterior ao [ASPNET CORE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/), porque, é da mesma forma, só lembrando os passo:

- decorando o `FinishDate` com o `DateTimeCompare`
- e adicionando o `javascript` ([jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)).

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Classe ValidationAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Interface IclientValidatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [Interface IClientModelValidator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.validation.iclientmodelvalidator)
- [client-side validation in custom validation attribute - asp.net mvc 4 - SO<sup>En</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726404/client-side-validation-in-custom-validation-attribute-asp-net-mvc-4)
- [How to create Custom Data Annotation Validators - SO<sup>En</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413715/how-to-create-custom-data-annotation-validators)
- [Custom Unobtrusive jQuery Validation With DataAnnotations in MVC 3](https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/tag/custom-unobtrusive-validation/)
- [Criando uma Validação Customizada para o CPF – Custom Validation Attribute](http://mmaspnetmvc.blogspot.com.br/2014/10/criando-uma-validacao-customizada-para.html)
- [Introduction to ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/)

Comment: É isso ai mesmo obrigado @virgilio qual a grande necessidade de uma validação no cliente?

Comment: @WallaceReis você obriga a informação ir para o servidor mais formatada possivel, e isso pode ser economia de banda já visto que seu form já tem uma pre - validação... !!! e não precisa ficar enviando várias vezes para conferir. é uma boa prática ter, mas, o essencial é a do servidor essa é garantia de eficiencia